# Identifying mathematical formulas from the query string

Tags: java, regex

I've been hacking my brain over this since yesterday and would appreciate some pointers. I will receive Where Query Statements as input as given,

```
(((REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/REVENUE_M1)*100 >= 10 AND ((REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/REVENUE_M1)*100 < 50) OR CLASS_DENOM = 2001
```

I'm tokenizing the statement as shown below,

```
[(((REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/REVENUE_M1)*100, >, =, 10, AND, ((REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/REVENUE_M1)*100, <, 50), OR, CLASS_DENOM, ==, 2001]
```

This is the regular expression that I have used - `([^\"]\S*|\".+?\")\s*` - which will identify tokens starting with something other than `" \S*` followed by zero or more non-space characters.

But now from the first token I'm trying to identify the formula `((REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/REVENUE_M1)*100` without including the `(` used for precedence and which is where I'm getting stuck. Here's my code,

```
List tokenizer(String str){
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")\\s*").matcher(str);
    while (m.find())
        tokens.add(m.group(1));
    return tokens;
}
    
void parser(String str) {
    for(String token : tokenizer(str)) {
        if(token.matches("regex to identify mathematical formula"))
            //parse the formula
    }
}
```

So my question is how I should frame the regex so that it will identify only `((REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/REVENUE_M1)*100` without including the `(` used for precedence?

Comment: It is not a wise idea to use a regex instead of a proper parser (generator) to parse complicated expressions.

Comment: What is the difference between your current output `((REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/REVENUE_M1)*100` and your desired output `((REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/REVENUE_M1)*100`?

Comment: Agree with the above comment +1.  Your time would be better spent learning how to write a rudimentary expression parser here.

Comment: Furthermore, why are you matching `\"`? It never appears in your original expression

Comment: What I've asked here is just a tiny part of the big picture. So maintaining a parser here would lead to a lot of changes which is why I'm trying to solve it like this

Comment: @WaisKamal: please take a look at the first token in the list and NOT the 6th. As for ur second comment that regex is not only to support this statement but all statements in general.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want your tokeniser function to return. Can you give a complete list of the tokens you would like it to produce for your input string.

Comment: @tgdavies: I'm trying to iterate the elements in the list. The first element is `(((REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/REVENUE_M1)*100`. I'm trying to create a regex that can identify `((REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/REVENUE_M1)*100` from first element. Pls take a look at the updated code.

Comment: What does "identify (...)" mean? Match that string exactly?

Comment: @tgdavies: Yes. I'm trying to build a regex that will match mathematical expressions like `REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1`  or `(REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/1000`.

Comment: What's your definition of a mathematical expression? You must specify what rules they will follow before anyone can suggest a regex to match them.

Comment: @tgdavies: An expression will be of format <lhs><operator><rhs>. lhs & rhs can be numbers like `100` or columns like `REVENUE_M2`. Operator can be `-+/*`. An expression can be enclosed with brackets for precedence like `(REVENUE_M2-REVENUE_M1)/1000`.

Comment: Is your end goal to evaluate the expressions as you parse them, or to produce a syntax tree? Regexes can't really parse, so you should use a parser, e.g. https://github.com/jparsec/jparsec/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: My end goal is to build a custom syntax tree from the expression. To do that I need to first identify the expression from the statement which is what I've asked.